# How does an iPhone app interact with CouchDB?

Tags: ios, server

I recently got an internship as an iOS developer and have been told to research on a couple of concepts. I will be coding on an iOS application and my employer stated that they have a couchDB server which the iOS application will interact with to get the data. They told me that the iOS app interacts with the node server to fetch data from the database. I am a little confused on what they mean by node server? Are they referring to the node server as in the couchDB database?

I understand this is a very general question and probably really bad, but if anyone can give me insight on how an iPhone application interacts with the node server that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying CouchDB in the wild it is common to not expose port 5984/6984 to the open internet, rather proxy requests to Couch via Nginx or a bespoke proxy app to handle:

- SSL Termination (mochiweb that ships with CouchDB does not handle newer cyphers as well)
- Authentication (do you need to duplicate user accounts in Couch for eg?)
- Access logging
- ...or other cross-cutting concerns you want to keep off your db server.

NodeJs is a good choice for writing an app that proxys Couchdb to the open internet that is JSON & HTTP all the way down, as it were.  My guess is that is what your employer means.

Comment: Ohhh ok, that definitely cleared things up. Thank you so much! The three examples were perfect!

Comment: Just curious. I am a little new to this... but does every database have a different port for the UDP/TCP transport layers?

Comment: I'll keep it brief because that is on the way to being a whole new question!  But no, the default ports for CouchDB are 5985 for HTTP and 6984 for HTTPS (when using mochiweb for built-in SSL).  The reason this comment is still on-topic for your Q (I hope :-) is a further  reason to use a proxy: Ports 80 & 443 are often unimpeded, for better or worse, by firewalls whereas 5984/6984 you can expect will be blocked somewhere.  Every DB on the server will be accessible on the same port however, whatever that port turns out to be when viewed from the client.

Comment: Oh ok! Thanks for replying! Do you happen to have any good resources where I can maybe get a better understanding of this?

Comment: Check out guide.couchdb.org,  day.couchdb.org (c.2015) and conf.couchdb.org (c.2013).  Drink deeply of those three and you'll be well on the way.